# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined even working on console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to include jQuery in js file since it would be loaded as a external script.

Here is my code:

```
function addjQuery() {
  if (!window.jQuery) {
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    jq.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);
    console.log("Added jQuery!");
  } else {
    console.log("jQuery already exists.")
  }
}
addjQuery();

jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
  });
});
```

But error occurs:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Even when I run "jQuery" or "$" on console of chrome dev tool, it's working.

What's the problem?

Comment: the jQuery() function is running prior to the library getting loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jQuery()` function is firing prior to jQuery being loaded from the script tag - you can add an `onload` event handler to fire it when the script is done downloading:

```
function addjQuery() {
  if (!window.jQuery) {
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    jq.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);
    jq.onload = initjQuery;
    console.log("jQuery is loaded!");
  } else {
    console.log("jQuery already exists.")
  }
}

function initjQuery () {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() { });
  });
}

addjQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it's really helpful.